# PHP - run script in background

Tags: php, background

I have to execute a php script (test.php) in the background. I tried this but it's not working:

```
<?
$cmd = "php /home/megad404/www/prove/test.php &> /dev/null &";
exec('/bin/bash -c "'.$cmd.'"',$output,$return);
if($return===0)
{
    echo 'Successful';
} 
else
{
    echo 'Unsuccessful';
}
?>
```

It returns "Successful" but it doesn't execute test.php

test.php:

```
<?
file_put_contents(date("s"),"");
sleep(5);
file_put_contents(date("s"),"");
sleep(5);
file_put_contents(date("s"),"");
?>
```

test.php writes a file every 5 second and it works fine, except if I try to execute it in the background with the first script.

Could it be a server issue? Is there another way to run a script in the background?

Answer (score 2):

Use shell_exec and nohup

```
shell_exec("nohup php /home/megad404/www/prove/test.php > /dev/null & echo $!");
```

Comment: Open console and write command `php /home/megad404/www/prove/test.php`. See result or error exception. I hope you use *nix OS and you had set the environment variable php

Comment: How do I open the console?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but, how I know that? I think that my problem is related to permission. I just set all to 777 but now i can't connect to the server to see if it works

Answer (score 0):

Use shell_exec and give absolute path for php:

```
$output = shell_exec("nohup /usr/bin/php7.0 -f /home/megad404/www/prove/test.php &> /dev/null &");
```

Just confirm the absolute path for php in your server. For instance, I'm using php 7.0 and the absolute path is /usr/bin/php7.0

Also, give executable permission to the php file you are running from your code.

```
chmod +x /home/megad404/www/prove/test.php
```